# TAB in CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor

If I press TAB between two words in Libreoffice, then a TAB gets inserted between these words. See this screenshot and the blue arrow:

[image]

If I do the same in CKEditor, then the whole line gets moved to the right. See this screenhost and the blue arrow:

[image]

Is there a way to configure CKEditor to behave like libreoffice?

Comment: Tab characters in HTML are interpreted as simple spaces, so I don't think it can be done.

Comment: @Wizard in my case TAB does not insert spaces. It does what I painted in violet. It does increase the indentation of the whole line.

Comment: I know, but if you modify its behavior, it can only be interpreted as a single space, which isn't what you want anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have highlighted with violet color is for increasing an indent of the paragraph and it is not for inserting a tab in between words.

[Definition](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/i/indent.htm)

> When referring to text, indent or indentation is the increase or
>   decrease of space between the left and right margin of a paragraph. In
>   many programs, an indent for the first line of text can be created by
>   moving the cursor to the front of the line and pressing the tab key on
>   the keyboard.

You can set `tabSpaces` [config option](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-tabSpaces) to allow tabs in the editor.

Comment: In my setup of CKEditor hitting TAB does "indent paragraph". Is this the default? Looks a bit strange to me.

Comment: @guettli Can you post jsfiddle/source with reproduced issue?

Comment: Thank you for asking for a jsfiddle. While setting it up, I found the solution. There was a custom plugin of a team mate which I did not know before. This plugin uses TAB to do indentation. Sorry for the confusion. Thank you for the "tabSpaces" config option. This solves my question.